# Is it meaningful to store workitem URIs

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm considering storing the URI for a workitem from our TFS environment in our helpdesk system, however looking at the URIs TFS gives us (vstfs:///WorkItemTracking/WorkItem/327), there doesn't appear any recognition of which team project it is associated with, which makes me wonder how meaningful they are?

Is it possible to load a workitem by just URI? Or will I have to store the Project URI as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The work item URI is unique across the Team Foundation Server in TFS 2008/2005 or across the entire Project Collection in TFS 2010 (TFS 2010 has a new notion of project collections - see [here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/tfs_2010_api_by.html) for more information).  The Team Project that it is in does not affect the ID.

Therefore to have a unique reference to the work item so that you'll always be able to get to it in the future you need a TFS server URI and a Work Item URI (i.e. http://tfsserver:8080/ + vstfs:///WorkItemTracking/WorkItem/327)

If you will only ever have a single TFS server or a single TFS project collection in TFS 2010 that your CRM system is attached to then you can assume all work items are linked to a single TFS Url.

Answer (score 2):

The URI is meaningful since the item number at the end of the URI is unique and links to the item in TFS.  I think storing this URI in another system makes sense considering the fact that it contains the identifier of the item.

Comment: I appreciate that it is the id, but is it unique across a server, or only across the project?

Comment: The ID is unique across the entire TFS instance, no two projects will share the same ID for any two items.